# Fuzz Ball hypothesis of Black holes

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-information, string-theory, quantum-gravity, hawking-radiation

A little help please.
How does the fuzz ball hypothesis using string theory solve the information paradox?
I have heard people who know the subject far better than me say that it in fact does but i dont get how?
I mean it does provide a place for the information or micro states to reside on the event horizon while in a relativistic black hole it wasn't possible. ( I mean Beckenstein gave his no hair theorem and said that the hidden states must've been present within the event horizon but then came along Hawking radiation and messed with the information conservation law and the rest is history).
Well, I also know HRadiation is completely random within the event horizon and so information is lost once the BH evaporates, but if it's going to evaporate anyway what difference does the fuzz ball hypothesis make. I mean, sure we can now observe the micro states but they are still lost when it evaporates right, how does that solve the information paradox? Is the fact that in one of them, the microstates are unobservable and observable in the other the only difference. I can see that this assumption of mine is wrong, that I am missing something so can someone enlighten me.

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because I'm not a string theory, so I'm mostly guessing: doesn't the formation of a fuzzball means no black hole is ever formed? If so, then it seems to be that the Hawking calculation simply does not apply, and hence there is no evaporation because there is not even a black hole to evaporate. It still looks might like a black hole from afar though.

Comment: My guess (in fact, almost everything I know about fuzzballs) is based on the brief discussions on https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02140 (which actually criticizes fuzzballs and other alleged solutions to the information "paradox")

Comment: Have a look at Mathur's [Fuzzballs and the information paradox: a summary and conjectures](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4525).

Comment: @NíckolasAlves ahh I get it all this while I have been taking the radiation from the fuzzball to be the same as the Hawking Radiation which is completely random, so this new kind of radiation which has much in common with the HRadiation like the same spectrum of energy signatures etc must not be a random process then, I mistook that they give almost the same kinds of radiations as being the same process, I think I need to study the paper suggested by A.V.S . Thanks both of you